# Visual Studio falsely reports Web Deploy provider not installed (SQL Azure)

Tags: .net, sql, visual-studio, azure, web-deployment

When attempting to deploy to SQL Azure with *Update database* enabled in the *Publish Web* dialog I get the following error:

> The remote host does not have the dbDacFx Web Deploy provider
>   installed, which is required for database publishing. To learn more
>   about this visit this link.
>
> FWLink: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=246068

**Using:** Visual Studio 2012 RTM, SQL Server 2012, Windows 7 Ultimate

**Project Type:** MVC 4.0 (API)

**Connection String:**

```
Server=tcp:SERVER.database.windows.net,1433;Database=DB_NAME;User ID=Me@Server;Password=PASSWORD;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;
```

**Other:** Firewall ports are open to my testing IP. Source DB is hosted on a local instance. Destination DB was originally set to the new "Preview" mode but I also replicated this under standard. No EntityFramework is being used (wouldn't allow for "Update database"). Disabled firewall while publishing, no effect.

Comment: Has it ever worked before? I'm guessing it's not a transient condition? As painful as it sounds, it might be worth attempting to deploy to a new web role/SQL db to see if it is localized to your specific instance.

Comment: No, it hasn't worked for me yet (though I'm confident Azure has the functionality). I did try deleting the entire database instance and creating a new one, unfortunately to the same effect.

Comment: Have you deleted the web role instance? Since the web deploy components live there, if there's a problem with them that may get you fixed - particularly if the web role instance has been running long enough that it hasn't been updated recently with any new web deploy components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dbDacFx did not exist for Windows Azure Web Sites until our most recent update this week. Please try again now and if you continue to receive errors let me know.

Comment: Thanks Shane, let me know if u run into any issues.